# « Il a s'écarté du droit chemin, » ou « Il est s'écarté du droit chemin. » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage

Someone is reviewing the curriculum vitae of another person and now has to pass judgement on it. His judgement is that this person has lost his real way of life and the sense of his life and that he will live and end really unhappily.

Comment: Quelle est la question ?

Comment: @Toto la question est dans le titre...

Comment: @LaurentS.: Bien sûr, mais ce n'est pas comme ça que l'on pose une question, d'autant plus que le corps de la « question » n'a strictement rien à voir avec le titre. Comment peut-on s'écarter du droit chemin dans un CV ?

Comment: @Toto. Merci pour la critique. Je suis nouveau ici et comme ca je fais des fautes de temps à temps. Mais je veux apprendre.Every advise is welcome!

Comment: On peut tout à fait avoir un parcours atypique et certains pourraient par exemple considérer que quelqu'un qui passe d'un poste à responsabilités vers quelquechose de moins prestigieux "s'écarte du droit chemin".

Comment: @LaurentS.C'est tout de même un peu tiré par les cheveux !

Comment: @Toto: En langue allemande (ma langue matrimoniale) nous disons comme ça si nous lison un CV comme Laurent à descrit.

Comment: @Sylvester "Matrimonial" and "maternel" sont un couple de mots dans lesquels la racine latine est "mater" (mère), mais "matrimonial" est spécialisé au mariage et ne signifie pas "qui est de la nature de la mère". Seule possibilité: langue maternelle.

Comment: @LPH Merci, j'ai mélangé les langues. Au l'école j'ai appris allemand, anglais francais et latin - mais l'enfance est passé dès beaucoup des années et je vois arriver la rente.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les verbes pronominaux prennent toujours l'auxiliaire `être`

Par contre aucune de vos propositions n'est correcte, la forme correcte est :

> Il s'est écarté du droit chemin

Comment: Thank you. Please help me - I am still looking for the checkmark to full accept an answer (like yours for example).

Comment: There's probably some time limitation preventing a very recent answer to a very recent question to be validated. Actually you should probably wait a few days before validating anyway so that other coming to your question are more inclined to answer and also that the answer that is validated is the best one. Now your question shouldn't bring a lot of other answers but still.

Comment: Thank you - just got the button. I think you are right ("wait a few days"), because yesterday there was none linked to my questions. I am really glad having found this site!!

Comment: Worth noting that in general, to my understanding, To my understanding, the basic order is usually `subject → ne → object → object → finite verb → pas → adverb → non finite-verb → adverb` with a few exceptions (e.g. *que*).